# Can't remove virtual host openlitespeed

Tags: ubuntu, caching, openlitespeed

i've installed fresh openlitespeed on ubuntu 20.

I have fresh "Example" config.

In Dashboard i see table with Listener & Virtual host.

Close to Virtual Host there is Pause button. When i click "Pause" nothing happen. When i remove Virtual Host it is still visible on Dashboard and still running.
When i create new virtual host, the new one is disabled, because "Example" virtual host has "*" in domains.

Can you help me, how to stop or remove virtual host on Open Lite Speed?

Update: 31.10.2021

[image]

[image]

After 1 day i've opened dasboard and i see, that Example is suspended, but second host has "Stopped" status, in domain column there is no domain (empty place), there is no "Pause/Start" button.
Additionaly SSL has icon with broken chain.

In VH config i've places correct path to certs and config file looks like that:

```
 virtualhost Example {
  vhRoot                  Example/
  configFile              conf/vhosts/Example/vhconf.conf
  allowSymbolLink         1
  enableScript            1
  restrained              1
  setUIDMode              0
}

virtualhost Manufakturakawy {
  vhRoot                  /usr/local/lsws/MyDomain/
  configFile              $SERVER_ROOT/conf/vhosts/MyDomain/vhconf.conf
  allowSymbolLink         1
  enableScript            1
  restrained              1
}

listener Default {
  address                 *:8088
  secure                  0
  map                     Example *
}

listener SSL {
  address                 *:443
  secure                  1
  map                     MyDomain www.mydomain.com
}

vhTemplate centralConfigLog {
  templateFile            conf/templates/ccl.conf
  listeners               Default
}

vhTemplate EasyRailsWithSuEXEC {
  templateFile            conf/templates/rails.conf
  listeners               Default
}
suspendedVhosts           Example
```

in vhconf.conf file i have:

```
    docRoot                   /var/www/html/mydomain/
vhDomain                  MyDomain.com
vhAliases                 www.MyDomain.com
enableGzip                1

rewrite  {
  enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.MyDomain.com/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.MyDomain.com/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  CACertPath              /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.MyDomain.com/fullchain.pem
  CACertFile              /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.MyDomain.com/fullchain.pem
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the suspend button? It works on my test server. See the image below,
[image: suspend]

After clicking the button, the server will add following command to the **/usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf** file automatically.

```
suspendedVhosts           Example
```

Also, remove feature works from my dashboard. Although you said it's a fresh installation, I feel it's like a permission issue somewhere so the dashboard is not able to do it for you. I'd check if there's any log generated in /usr/local/lsws/logs/error.log while you click the dashboard.

You can also update virtual host mapping from the config file manually via SSH console as a workaround method. Edit **/usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf**
From

```
listener wordpress {
  address                 *:80
  secure                  0
  map                     Example *
}
```

to

```
listener wordpress {
  address                 *:80
  secure                  0
  map                     virtualhostname example.com,www.example.com
}
```

Then restart the webserver

```
systemctl restart lsws
```

Comment: Hi, i've updated my post, can you take a look?

Comment: Sure. There's an issue in "listener SSL", you need to give it a cert & key, any cert should be fine, so it won't show in red status more.  Let me know if it fixed the vh issue as well.